# Explode rows with number ranges into one row per number

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like this:

| from | to | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | invalid |
| 10 | 15 | valid |

How can I efficiently `SELECT` or produce a result like this:

| serial | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | invalid |
| 2 | invalid |
| 3 | invalid |
| 10 | valid |
| 11 | valid |
| 12 | valid |
| 13 | valid |
| 14 | valid |
| 15 | valid |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the column that is named `from` (reserved keyword), the query is simple:

```
SELECT generate_series("from", "to") AS serial, status
FROM T
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lateral join`.

```sql
with t ("from", "to", status) as (values (1, 3, 'invalid'), (10, 15, 'valid'))
select l.val serial, t.status status
from t 
cross join lateral generate_series(t."from", t."to", 1) as l(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a calendar table approach we can try:

```sql
WITH nums AS ( 
    SELECT generate_series(1, 15) AS num
)

SELECT n.num AS serial, t.status
FROM nums n
INNER JOIN yourTable t
    ON n.num BETWEEN t."from" AND t."to"
ORDER BY n.num;
```

### Demo

Note in the event that your actual data could have from-to ranges which might overlap, you may want to consider adding a primary key to your table.  This primary key could then be used in ordering the output as you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

first CTE is your table,so:

```
with _data as (
select * from (values (1,3,'invalid'), (10,15,'valid')) as t("from","to","status")
)

SELECT generate_series(_data.from, _data.to) AS serial,
_data.status
from _data
```

produces

```
1   invalid
2   invalid
3   invalid
10  valid
11  valid
12  valid
13  valid
14  valid
15  valid
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalized solution would require a recursive query:

- base step gathers current records
- recursive step adds 1 to "*from*", till "*from*" reaches the "*to*" value.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT from_ + 1 AS from_, to_, status
    FROM cte
    WHERE from_ + 1 <= to_ 
)
SELECT from_ AS serial, status 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY from_, to_
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/frLaWusnnLNL8efZwcVio7/0).